does "a plurality" mean more than one or at least one?
Does "a plurality" strictly mean more than one or would it also encompass at least one?
Would there be any significant difference between using "a plurality" versus "multiple"?


Does "a plurality" strictly mean more than one or would it also encompass at least one?

Plurality means more than one, so that "at least one" is broader.

Would there be any significant difference between using "a plurality" versus "multiple"?

If you introduce "a plurality of widgets" you can cleanly refer to it later as "said plurality of widgets". This doesn't work out as nicely with "multiple". (Nor with "at least one" but "said at least one" is used more commonly than "said multiple").
